# Adding data in Excel file without closing it

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I am currently using Apache POI to enter data into Excel file. The only problem is I can not keep the file open if I have to append data to the same file. Are there any specific sample codes which would allow me to do so? 
My basic requirement is to fetch Runtime data from a place (this I am able to do) and add it to the Excel sheet while the file is still open. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible without a C# addon or some kind of macro. You could write a simple C# addon for Excel that connects to your java programm and recieves the realtime data. The addon will write it to the spreadsheat then.

Comment: So will it be similar to building an RTD server?

Comment: Yes, but just with a small C# part that more or less executes commands that are recieved by the Java application.